# Selecting lossyear polygon of Hansen data

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, boolean

I'm working with Hansen database in Google Earth Engine.

I would like to select polygon of two different years for example 2010 and 2011 for a certain area using lossyear map.

This is my code:

```
var hansen =ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2017_v1_5')
.clipToCollection(area)
.select(['lossyear']);
var 10 = loss_year.eq(10);
var 11 = loss_year.eq(11);
```

To create a unique map I think to use the command `.and()` so

```
var map = 10.and(11);
```

When I display the result, the map is not visible why?

Comment: variables should not be numbers. Also, you should post a representative code that can reproduce the error. You have not posted the lines where you `addLayer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, got it. I don't know javascript, so either logical operators don't work the way I'd expect or (my guess) EE requires working with the purpose-built functions like `and()` and `or()` which I guess aren't defined over `eq()`.

The simplest way to do this is with band math. Just add the images together:

```js
var hansen = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2017_v1_5")
var year2016=hansen.select(['lossyear']).eq(16)
var year2012=hansen.select(['lossyear']).eq(12)
var bothYears=year2016.add(year2012)

Map.addLayer(year2016.updateMask(year2016),{palette:['FF0000']},'year2016')
Map.addLayer(year2012.updateMask(year2012),{palette:['00FF00']},'year2012')
Map.addLayer(bothYears.updateMask(bothYears),{palette:['0000FF']},'bothYears')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot the command Map.addLayer. I tried with your command and function. However I didn't obtain my aim because final map considers only 1 class (for example 16) the same if I use and operator instead of and. While I'm interesting to have in the same map both class (for the example 16 and 12). Why?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, but is it the case you want lossyear=16 AND lossyear=12 to be included in the map? In that case use the "OR" operator. This should subject the values in each pixel of your image layer to a logical test that returns 'true' if the value is 12 OR 16. I.e. you get both year=12 and yea r- 16 in the result. Use of the "AND" operator should return a blank layer, because no pixel contains the value 12 as well as the value 16. I'm not sure though - play around a bit & post the result?

Comment: Yes I want this situation in my final map- I tried and I found a solution. This is the command: hansen.eq(16).or(hansen.eq(12)); Thanks a lot for your help!